# Break line in innerHTML - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div called box and I want to change it's content using javascript.

```
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is a sentence';
```

But i want it to look like

```
This is

a sentence
```

I tried

```
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is\ a sentence';
```

and

```
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is\na sentence';
```

but none of them works.

Comment: Try document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is <br><br> a sentence';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is<br/>a sentence';`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is<br> a sentence';
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is<br> a sentence';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to have 1 line empty between your two parts:

```
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is<br/><br/>a sentence';
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not respect newline characters (\n) when it comes to rendering text. Instead, use HTML to break up your text, such as a `<br/>` tag:

`document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'This is<br/> a sentence';`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also use `<pre>` tag with `\n`

```js
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "<pre>" + "This is" + "\n" + "a sentence"+ "</pre>";
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

**Output:**

```
This is
a sentence
```